# While navigation to a path using React Router, the component state value gets reset to default

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using React-Routerv4 , and when I login using the login form , i set the app component state value `isUser` to true from child component login using function `setUserLogin`, which i can debug correctly in the console after logging in. Also I have specified , that if i migrate to `/login` path ,it checks `isUser` value in state to migrate to `/home page` if user is already logged in(`isUser` is `true`) . But that value is now automatically changed to default value `false` , when i enter `/login` in the browser and it shows login page instead of home page. Im new to React , so am I missing something here? 
Here is the code snippet :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import 'materialize-css/bin/materialize.css'
import 'materialize-css/bin/materialize.js';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route , Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import {LoginForm} from './components/login';
import {Home} from './components/home';
import {Main} from './components/main';
import {Room} from './components/room';
import "materialize-css";
import 'materialize-css/js/toasts';


class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            isUser : false
        }
        this.setUserLogin = this.setUserLogin.bind(this);
    }
    setUserLogin(){
        this.setState({isUser:true});
    }
    render() {
        return <Router>
            <div>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route path="/login" render={(props)=>(
                    this.state.isUser ? <Redirect to="/home" /> : <LoginForm history={props.history} setUserLogin = {this.setUserLogin}/>
                )} />
                <Route path="/home" component={Main}/>
                <Route path="/room" component={Room}/>
            </div>
        </Router>
    };
}
ReactDom.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your situation, do you expect your state to persist when you manually change your URL in the browser? If you want this, you'll have to store some variable in persistent storage (like localStorage) and check it at some point of component life cycle: constructor, componentDidMount...

When you manually change your browser location, everything restarts including the state, the whole page is redownloaded (or read from cache).

Comment: Does this mean when i change the url , all my states in all components will be lost unless I save it in local storage? Shouldnt atleast the topmost level app component not reinitialize?

Comment: I don't think react (or any JS) can intercept a change in your browser url. React router can handle this when the URL is changed inside the app using a <Link>, but not a manual change in the URL. Login is the typical situation where you'll have to persist something: a token, a session id... Other state attributes will have to be recomputed in the constructor.