# Changing state of parent element in Reactjs resetting state of all <Route /> based components elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Basically changing `<Parent />` is resetting children state. Only for components attached to `<Route />`

I was able to duplicate issue in codepen

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BZVdzE

```
var BrowserRouter =ReactRouterDOM.BrowserRouter;
var Route =ReactRouterDOM.Route;
var Link = ReactRouterDOM.Link;

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      title: "blank"
    };
  }
  changeText(x) {
    this.setState({ title: x });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="btn" onClick={this.changeText.bind(this, 1)}>1</div>
        <div className="btn" onClick={this.changeText.bind(this, 2)}>>2</div>
        <div className="btn" onClick={this.changeText.bind(this, 3)}>>3</div>
        <p> {this.state.title}</p>
        <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path='/' component={(props) => <Child  {...props} state={this.state} />} /> 
        </ BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      favoriteColor: "none choosen"
    };
  }
  changeColor(color) {
    this.setState({favoriteColor: color});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="btn" onClick={this.changeColor.bind(this, 'Green')}>Green</div>
        <div className="btn" onClick={this.changeColor.bind(this, 'Purple')}>Purple</div>
        <div className="btn" onClick={this.changeColor.bind(this, 'Brown')}>Brown</div>
        <p> {this.state.favoriteColor} </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Choose favorite color, change number, favorite color goes to default value.

Comment: Please include a code sample to illustrate the problem you're having.

Comment: I think this might be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44411830/while-navigation-to-a-path-using-react-router-the-component-state-value-gets-re

Comment: @DavidL.Walsh ok made a codepen check it out